# How to allow mobile devices, (e.g. Phones, Tablets) to have access to python flask server using HTTPS

Tags: python-3.x, flask, https

```
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=443,threaded=True,ssl_context=(
    'certs/mydomain.com_bundle.crt',
    'certs/mydomain.com.key'),debug=False)
```

This is my code in flask.

The strange things is, I can use PCs like MAC OS and WINDOWS to enter the website using HTTPS, no warnings at all and all certificates are shown as secured. But I just can't enter it using my mobile devices like my phone and my android tablet. Haven't tried iPad or iPad pro yet cause I don't have one.

All errors are "REFUSED TO CONNECT". That seems pretty much to be a problem in the program.

However if I switch it to HTTP & PORT=80 , I can enter it using basically all devices.

So does anyone know how to allow mobile devices to enter it using HTTPS as well?

Comment: What OS is your python server running on? make sure the firewall of the OS is configured to allow connections on port 443.

Answer (score 0):

My bad.

For some unknown reasons, my phone's browser didn't use HTTPS, it used HTTP as url proxy instead.

In the best of my knowledge, most browsers set HTTPS as the first priority for connections, yet the chromes in both of my mobile devices used HTTP, so did the default browsers...

So changing the url proxy to HTTPS fixed the problem, just that simple.